# Python machine-communication on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have 3 machines (raspberry pi's). One has a database of sensor readings on, the other two are 'slave' devices that read/run various sensors. what is the best solution to allow the 'master' pi to access sensor readings on the 'slave' pis- so it can save the values to the database.

All the pis are on the same internal network, and will never be on the internet
The 'slave' pis return integers to the master pi, that is all.
It has to be python3 (because the software that queries the sensors is)

What is the very simplest way?

- Some kind of web service? I've so far failed to get get pysimplesoap and cherrypy to work on python3.
- Something else? Pyro? It seems a bit complicated just to get back 2 integers.
- Roll my own with sockets (that can't be the easiest way?!)
- Give up and put a mysql database on each pi, then make the 'sensor-value-reporting-website' stretch across 3 databases/hosts.

Comment: Why isn't roll your own with sockets not the simplest? Is python's tcp library so low level that it looks more like C and isn't simple?

Comment: If python makes TCP programming non-simple then I suggest trying something that does - like node.js or tcl.

Comment: Another work-around to simplify TCP programming (in any language) is to use inetd (or xinetd). Your server then only needs to read stdin and prints out to stdout. It's kind of like CGI for plain sockets.

Comment: I ended up using bottle - http://bottlepy.org. It was the only thing that worked out of the box on python3. I couldn't even get SimpleHttpSocket to do anything useful (it could return a directory listing! but I couldn't make it do anything else, and I was in a bit of a hurry)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest simple REST server on the slaves, and client on the master.

The slaves can return ints as JSON, which you can easily parse on the master.

See simple server sample:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

Answer (score 1):

I would have a mySQL database on the master only and have the slaves write their own tables to that database using the cymysql python3 module
(pip3 install cymysql)